# strange firefox search string 'DME'

Tags: firefox, keyword

Whenever I search for some word. I usually type it in address bar of firefox. Firefox promptly returns the search result for that word in google search.

Recently I was searching abbreviation for DME. But when I typed DME in firefox I always get connection timed out error.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

Firefox is assuming "dme" is a domain name (local domains don't have to have dots in them). Only if you enter a character that can't be in a domain name (like a space or quote mark) will it do a search.